# Always get Internal Server Error with NodeJS/Passport (BattleNet Strategy)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

folks.  I'm working on a tiny app using OAuth (via Battle.Net) and PassportJS + Express, and I keep getting an Internal Server Error no matter what I do.

I've read their code numerous times, tried using ES6 syntax and ES5 syntax (I'm using `babel-watch` for transpiling), to no avail.

This is my current Express setup using the BNet Passport Strategy:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import session from 'express-session';
import passport from 'passport';

const BnetStrategy = require('passport-bnet').Strategy;

// Get our stuff from env vars
const BNET_ID = process.env.BNET_ID;
const BNET_SECRET = process.env.BNET_SECRET;

// Our GQL stuff
import resolvers from './gql/resolvers';
import typeDefs from './gql/typeDefs';

// Express Stuff
const app = express();

// Integrate Apollo middleware
const gqlServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});

// Passport User serialize/deserialize
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    return done(null, user)
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
    return done(null, obj)
});

// Passport middleware w/ bnet?
passport.use(new BnetStrategy({
        clientID: BNET_ID,
        clientSecret: BNET_SECRET,
        scope: ['wow.profile'],
        region: 'us',
        passReqToCallback: true,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/bnet/callback"
    },
    (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        console.log(req.user, accessToken, profile);
        return done(null, profile)
    })
);

app.get('/auth/bnet', passport.authenticate('bnet'));
app.get('/auth/bnet/callback', passport.authenticate('bnet', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
)

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    var output = '<h1>Express OAuth Test</h1>' + req.user.id + '<br>';
    if(req.user.battletag) {
      output += req.user.battletag + '<br>';
    }
    output += '<a href="/logout">Logout</a>';
    res.send(output);
  } else {
    res.send('<h1>Express OAuth Test</h1>' +
             '<a href="/auth/bnet">Login with Bnet</a>');
  }
});

// Listen!
app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () => {
    console.log(`GQL server is listening at http://localhost:4000${gqlServer.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

When I flush the cookies from my browser and visit the server's index page, it lets me login using my BNet account, and even triggers the Mobile Authenticator on my phone (which I accepted), but then after I accept the auth on my phone, it tosses this error:

```
AuthorizationError: Internal server error
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate (/home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:131:25)
    at attempt (/home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:361:16)
    at authenticate (/home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:362:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/czbaker/Projects/wow-warmode/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

I've checked callbacks for all of the functions to see that they're formatted correctly (returning `done(null, <value>)` seems to be a big thing people miss, after looking around at similar issues, but it's fine here.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, so any assistance would be super appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Needless to say, "Internal Server Error" is pretty useless as far as debugging goes.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was that the callback URL needed to use HTTPS, as is a requirement from the OAuth2 API on Blizzard's end, and I failed to realize that.

Upon setting up SSL/HTTPS on my Express server, everything worked fine, so I guess the JS error itself wasn't super helpful.